# Shade smooth render looks like Shade Flat

Tags: rendering

View-port model has smooth shading:
[image]

Look-Dev mode looks smooth shaded:
[image]

But the Final Render has noticeable edges:

[image]

Is there a reason as to why it's like that?

Comment: Do you have a subdivision modifier on the object set to *Simple* that is only active for rendering and not for edit mode or the viewport?

Comment: @rjg  ... could also be different viewport/render subdiv. levels, in the modifier, simple or not..

Comment: @rjg That's doesn't seem to be the case. It's set to cat mull-Clark, Rendering and view-port icons are checked and the rendering & view-port subdivisions are both set to 1.

Comment: I have some ideas of what could cause this, but I'd like to see your blend file first if possible, with textures packed in (to do this, simply use the menu File→External Data→Pack All into .blend, then File→Save as, save as a new file with "packed" in the name, and eventually check the "compress" option before saving so you file remains as light as possible.

Comment: @L0Lock I've updated my question with the link. If the file crashes upon opening, then try opening blender and use the open function or ctrl+O

Comment: Nice model, btw. (Though I have to say I've never seen one painted blue before.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the color space of your normal map from sRGB to non-color in the texture node should fix your problem.
[image: color space]